# How do I separate the result of an sql query?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

So I have dynamically implemented text fields on my form using jQuery and then used it to insert in my database. Now I have been encountered with two problems, one being every time user posts the form entries, I have all the entries inside on row separated by comma. And secondly, when I retrieve the same from database, I get the row as a whole. What I want is every word individually in a separate div. Here is the code for both:

form.php

```
<?php 
include "init.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
      <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/animation.css">

      <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    </head>

    <body>
          <form action ="result.php" method="post">

                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="input-field col s4 green-text text-lighten-3">

                        <input name="set_name" type="text" class="validate">
                        <label for="set_name">Set Name</label>

                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="details">
                    </div>


                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>


                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light orange darken-4 text" type="submit" id="" name="action">Save
                    </button>

                    <div class="right bottom">
                    <a class="btn-floating btn-large waves-effect waves-light pink add_field_button"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>  
                    </div>
                  </form>

      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function() {
          var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
          var wrapper         = $(".details"); //Fields wrapper
          var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

          var x = 1; //initlal text box count
          $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
              e.preventDefault();
              if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
                  x++; //text box increment
                  $(wrapper).append('<div class="row"><div class="input-field col s6 green-text text-lighten-3"><input name="word[]" type="text" class="validate"><label for="word[]">Word</label></div><div class="input-field col s6 green-text text-lighten-3"><input name="def[]" type="text" class="validate"><label for="def">Definition</label></div><a class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue-grey darken-4 remove_field"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>  </div>'); //add input box
              }
      });

      $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
          e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
      })
  });
  </script>
</body>
```

And here is the result.php

```
<?php 
include "init.php";
$name = $_POST["set_name"];
if($_POST){
    $word = implode(",", $_POST["word"]);
    $def = implode(",", $_POST["def"]);
    echo $word;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $def;
}
$sql_query = "insert into table values('$name', '$word', '$def');";
if(mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query)) {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Inserted!")';
        echo '</script>';

    }
    else {
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Error in database, cannot insert.")';
        echo '</script>';
    }


$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT set_word FROM ayush95 WHERE set_name = 'Hindi';");
if($result->num_rows > 0){

    echo $result->fetch_object()->set_word;

}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `explode` php function. Here is an example from PHP doc.

```
// Example 1
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
```

Answer (score 0):

TheZozoOwner is partially correct; however, that code will still echo out all on one line.

If you want it echoed out on individual lines, try this...

```
$pieces = explode(",", $result->fetch_object()->set_word);
$count = count($pieces);

for($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) {
echo $pieces[$i].'<br>';
}
```